# Java to C# Encryption Conversion

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I have tried several attempts to port this code over to C# but I can not seem to get the outputs to match. Can someone help point me in the direction of what I am missing. I have included the actual code as well as links to online tools to run the samples and see the results.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
 
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
 
public class JavaEncryption {
 
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    private static void processEncryptionKey(String secret)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] base_hash = new byte[20];
            base_hash = crypt.digest();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) buffer [i] = 0x36;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) buffer [i] ^= base_hash[i];

            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            byte[] final_hash = new byte[20];
            final_hash = crypt.digest();
            key = Arrays.copyOf(final_hash, 16); 
             secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            processEncryptionKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            processEncryptionKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    final String secretKey = "YVr_wlp8_fFa";

    System.out.println("Secret = " + secretKey);

    String originalString = "testing";
    
    System.out.println("Clear text = " + originalString);

    String encryptedString = JavaEncryption.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
    System.out.println("Encrypted = " + encryptedString);

    String decryptedString = JavaEncryption.decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey);
    System.out.println("Decrypted = " + decryptedString);
  }
}
```

Here is the C# code I am trying to use but not getting the same result. I'm hoping it is just something small that I am missing:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class CSharpEncryption
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new CSharpEncryption().EncryptText());
    }
    
        public string EncryptText()
        {
            using (var aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                aes.Key = CreateSecretKey();
                aes.IV = new byte[16];
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                byte[] encrypted = GetEncryptedBytes("testing", aes.Key, aes.IV);
                string encString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

                return encString;
            }
        }

        protected byte[] GetEncryptedBytes(string textToEncrypt, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            byte[] encrypted;

            using (var rij = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rij.Key = Key;
                rij.IV = IV;

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = rij.CreateEncryptor(rij.Key, rij.IV);

                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                        {
                            sw.Write(textToEncrypt);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return encrypted;
        }

        private static byte[] CreateSecretKey()
        {
            var keyHash = CreateHashedKey();

            byte[] key = null;
            using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyHash, new byte[16], 1))
            {
                key = rfc2898.GetBytes(16);
            }

            return key;
        }

        private static string CreateHashedKey()
        {
            var hashBase64 = String.Empty;
            using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("YVr_wlp8_fFa"));

                hashBase64 = CreateBase64Hash(hash, true);
            }
            return hashBase64;
        }

        private static string CreateBase64Hash(byte[] arr, bool withoutPadding)
        {
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
            if (withoutPadding)
            {
                base64String = base64String.TrimEnd('=');
            }

            base64String += "\n";

            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ktULKG

Comment: Probably error in calculating big integers, java calculates in another way then in C#

Comment: What is the expected result? Easier to know it in advance without running java code.

Comment: The output from the java code is: 7z4ECK2P3181PKUKkIxsTQ==

The output from the c# code is: QKKBf7coPazZgFXP/l4hBw==

I need those to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codes differ in the key derivation. For instance, the C# code uses `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, which implements PBKDF2. But there is nothing of this in the Java code. So you just have to port the logic of `processEncryptionKey()` from the Java code to C#, e.g.:

```cs
private static byte[] ProcessEncryptionKey(string secret)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
        byte[] extHash = new byte[64];
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
            extHash[i] = (byte)(i < 20 ? hash[i]^0x36 : 0x36);
        }
        byte[] finHash = sha1.ComputeHash(extHash);
        byte[] secretKey = new byte[16];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(finHash, 0, secretKey, 0, secretKey.Length);
        return secretKey;
    }
}
```

which is called with `aes.Key = ProcessEncryptionKey("YVr_wlp8_fFa")` in `EncryptText()`. This gives the same ciphertext as the Java code.

Be aware that the code has vulnerabilities:

- As key derivation, a dedicated key derivation function such as PBKDF2 should be used.
- A static IV (like a zero IV) is insecure.

Comment: This is a huge help. Thank you. I didn't even notice that oversight. I am not great with encryption so I didn't even consider that. I was hoping it was just an easy fix that I was missing. As for the vulnerabilities, I just posted test code so the key derivation is auto generated so we should be ok there. As for the static IV, I will make a note of that and see about a change there. Very much appreciated.